In windows is it possible to configure proxy settings at the system level and not on the user level
windows proxy settings page
The settings I apply here is scoped to user only. Is there an option apply this configuration on machine level?

What do you mean? This is on machine level (That's why you need to be a Windows Adminstrator to change this setting.). You better explain what your problem is.

You can use the netsh command to set the proxy configuration for the whole system (including system services such as Windows update):
netsh winhttp set proxy <proxy>:<port>

Detailed help here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731131(v=ws.10)

So if proxy settings are configured via the netsh command... on which registry key the configuration details will be present?

I have no clue at all about this...

The user HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18 has it's key in Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections\DefaultConnectionSettings
